# H15 on Heroku SSE request

Tags: node.js, heroku, server-sent-events

I have a Node.js application on Heroku. I've recently switched a long query to use SSE (EventSource). While it works great and fast on my machine, I keep getting an `Error H15 (Idle connection)` on my GET request. The H15 description says I went over 55 seconds allowed per transaction. But my entire query doesn't take more than 4-5 seconds.

Furthermore, after reading the description, I'm returning my first byte (just a number) immediately upon hitting the query, before it starts any heavy work - and it still doesn't work.

My question/s are:

1. What do I need to do in order to keep this thing going? An HTTP header parameter? Something on the client JS side? How do I avoid H15?
2. Am I trying to do something not supported by Heroku? I don't think so, as I have another app on Heroku that uses EventSource successfully ([express-eventsource.herokuapp.com](http://express-eventsource.herokuapp.com), source on github: https://github.com/TravelingTechGuy/express-eventsource)

As always, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After trying everything, changing and re-writing my code, profiling the network etc., finally my friend (with no Node knowledge whatsoever) came up with an idea that put me on the right track:

It seems like this is a domain issue - NOT a code issue at all.
I set an ANAME mapping and it turns out that since Heroku uses 5 different IPs, mapping to just one of them can screw up an SSE call. Basically, mydomain.com showed an IP different than mydomain.herokuapp.com - meaning the server tried returning a response to a different IP than the one that initiated the call, hence it timed out.

I ditched the ANAME in favor of a CNAME (basically, giving up the naked mydomain.com in favor of www.mydomain.com) and now it seems to be working.

Conclusions:

1. Not everything is a code issue - if it works well in one environment and not in another, it's a configuration issue
2. If you struggle with something for too long, it helps to bring in a new set of eyes. Even with no subject matter expertise, you'll get great ideas to fresh approaches you can try
3. 1and1 DNS control sucks b@lls. Moving out of there

Comment: Just a short update: it was indeed a domain issue. All is working well (albeit slow - free Heroku == slow Heroku :)).

Comment: Ahh this problem is indeed irritating. Can you please elaborate in changing from ANAME to CNAME?

Comment: Basically, it means not using 'naked' domain names, like mydomain.com. Depending on your DNS control (I use GoDaddy), you should be able to set a subdomain (CNAME) through DNS management. See more here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Hey @TravelingTechGuy hopefully you are still around. I have an issue related to an SSE event route as well. I get the error `code=H27 desc="Client Request Interrupted" method=GET path="/sse-route"`. The route works well on my local but completely stops working on Heroku (except for when I first start the app). Its H27 and not H15. Of course, its not quite the same error as you but I am wondering if using a name mapping would solve this issue as well? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @philosopher. I'm still around . But I'm mostly off Heroku these days, so I can't really help, without doing research. Sorry.

Comment: What are you using instead

Comment: Currently, Netlify for quick deployments, or Lightsail for things more permanent (<$5/month from Amazon for a full server).

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem with a Meteor application. All of a sudden every interaction returned a websocket error on the application and a h15 error on the heroku. I have resolved it by changing the root url to a naked domain, and then forwarding the naked domain to a www.example.com. Hope this would also help someone. 
I also totaly agree with @TravelingTechGuy on

> Not everything is a code issue - if it works well in one environment and not in another, it's a configuration issue

Comment: Question is about SSE, web sockets are a completely different spec with their own set of complications.

Answer (score -4):

This may sometime cause because of the database. If the database is not connected the this error is likely to be visible!

Comment: SSE has nothing to do with database/s. See the proper answer below.