# Node.js Web Socket H15 Idle Connection timeout on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, websocket, timeout

We run a Node.js and Express application on Heroku that uses the [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) library for realtime web sockets. Below is a screen shot of the numerous H15 timeout's that we are seeing.

[image]

I've read that [Heroku terminates any idle connection after 55 seconds](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#timeouts) but our sockets send ping-pong back and forth every 5 seconds when the connection is open. A piece of the server code is below:

```
var _this = this;

this.server.on('connection', function(ws){

    // check for a ping, respond with pong
    ws.on('message', function(data){
        data = data.toString('utf8');
        if (data === PING) {
            ws.send(PONG);
        }
    });

    ws.on('close', function(err){
        TL.logger.info('Socket closed: '+path);
        _this.sockets = _.filter(_this.sockets, function(_ws){
            return ws != _ws;
        });
    });

    ws.on('error', function(err){
        TL.logger.info('Socket error: '+path);
        _this.sockets = _.filter(_this.sockets, function(_ws){
            return ws != _ws;
        });
    });

    _this.sockets.push(ws);
});
```

And here's a picture of client side socket in chrome:

[image]

Any idea's how to prevent the idle connection?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this at all?

Comment: Sadly no, we still have a bunch of seemingly random idle connections.

Comment: @Andrew We're getting the same errors some 2 years later. Did you ever find the cause?

Comment: Although I haven't gotten rid of them completely I am seeing them much less often by initiating the ping from the Node server rather than from the client. Also in the code above (very old, sorry!), I am sending the strings "ping" and "pong" but the websocket spec supports a real ping and pong frame and you should be sending that. If you're using `ws` for example it is just `ws.ping()` (and wrap that in a try catch)

Comment: Hi @Andrew, I know this question is old but I was having the same issue, here's my detailed answer in the case is useful for anyone else https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728030/heroku-h15-error-on-web-socket-close/59941248#59941248. Good luck, hope you're not getting those errors anymore.

Answer (score 2):

*disclosure: I'm the Node.js platform owner at Heroku.*

Are you seeing this on the client side? Or just the error-reporting dashboard?

I'd recommend focusing on reproducing the errors on at least one client, to see if there's actually any impact. Otherwise, you may be wasting time debugging false positives.

If you do decide to continue debugging, you may want to install a free papertrail / nodetime / new relic / strongloop addon to figure out exactly which requests are triggering the H15s.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! We don't use socket.io, just the ws module, and no I have yet to see any issues on the client, I just see the errors in the dashboard.

Comment: Ah sorry, most of the websocket-related questions are socket.io-based. I've updated my answer to reflect the ws library.

Comment: I get the same errors in an Meteor app (Meteor is based on Node), this post suggests it has to do with Heroku and root/apex/naked domains (ALIAS/ANAME etc), which we also use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063683/h15-on-heroku-sse-request

Comment: Hello, I know this is an old question but in 2020 I was still getting these errors and after debugging and testing I realized it was not a bug in my app but just the way Heroku Router works (maybe 5 years ago those errors were being displayed as critical in the dyno monitor). Anyway, in case this helps anyone here's my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728030/heroku-h15-error-on-web-socket-close/59941248#59941248