# socket.io on Heroku keeps giving me H15 idle connection errors

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, socket.io

I'm using socket.io for my app that's currently in production (on heroku) and I keep getting these errors. It seems like everything still works as it should though, but my logs get flooded with errors.

```
Jun 23 15:33:00 fixtrackapi heroku/router: at=error code=H15 desc="Idle connection" method=GET path="/ws/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=ZS_zSjEfTAkmA8GMAAAC" host=api.myurl.com request_id=18ca3817-009a-419f-8ef3-c598bc866bb4 fwd="84.194.46.28,54.155.253.188" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=119082ms status=503 bytes=189 
Jun 23 15:33:01 fixtrackapp heroku/router: at=error code=H15 desc="Idle connection" method=GET path="/ws/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=ZS_zSjEfTAkmA8GMAAAC" host=demo.myurl.com request_id=18ca3817-009a-419f-8ef3-c598bc866bb4 fwd="84.194.46.28" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=119741ms status=503 bytes=205 
Jun 23 15:34:10 fixtrackapi heroku/router: at=error code=H15 desc="Idle connection" method=GET path="/ws/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=w_vK_zsJv7BY9j7qAAAD" host=api.myurl.com request_id=d0a07db1-1cd1-4b3c-8229-c0fbc32a39db fwd="84.194.46.28,54.155.253.188" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=55231ms status=503 bytes=183 
Jun 23 15:34:11 fixtrackapp heroku/router: at=error code=H15 desc="Idle connection" method=GET path="/ws/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=w_vK_zsJv7BY9j7qAAAD" host=demo.myurl.com request_id=d0a07db1-1cd1-4b3c-8229-c0fbc32a39db fwd="84.194.46.28" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=55941ms status=503 bytes=199
```

As you can see there are 2 heroku apps reporting the errors at the ~same time, that is because 'fixtrackapp' is proxying the socket.io requests to my api server ('fixtrackapi').

client code:

```
const socket = io('', { path: '/ws' });
```

this is the proxying code:

```
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: targetUrl,
  changeOrigin: true,
  ws: true
});
app.use('/api', (req, res) => {
  proxy.web(req, res, {target: targetUrl + '/v1'});
});

app.use('/ws', (req, res) => {
  proxy.web(req, res, {target: targetUrl + '/ws'});
});
```

Api server code:

```
const app = express();
const server = new http.Server(app);
const io = socketio(server);
io.path('/ws');
const runnable = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on port ${port}`));
io.listen(runnable);
```

I've also tried by running my own keep alive on the client by using a setinterval, that sent a 'ping' every 8 seconds. But I still had the errors ( although it sometimes seemed like i got less of them).

Any idea what might be causing this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you Googled H15 and Heroku?  There are a lot of suggestions on how to deal with this.  The two most promising are insuring that you are pinging on the server side less than every 55 seconds.  Also, there are some discussions on verifying your DNS configuration.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063683/h15-on-heroku-sse-request

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I am using CNAME records, and yes I tried running a keep alive with as little as 8 seconds between pings. Sadly I still have the H15 problems. I'm afraid it has something to do with the proxying in between, but there are no suggestions that say anything about that.

Comment: @RobIndesteege We're seeing the same thing. Did you ever figure out the root cause?

Comment: @FajitaNachos I think they are just false positives, since everything works as it should. I just added a filter to hide the H15 logs and haven't spent any more time on it since.

Comment: Same here! We added auto-pings and they are still there.

Comment: Hello everyone, I was breaking my head around this problem too. I answered this issue here in the case is useful for anyone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728030/heroku-h15-error-on-web-socket-close/59941248#59941248